# Xubuntu 14.04: xfce4-session-settings modifications do not affect system

Tags: xubuntu, startup

I've added some modifications to the software that automatically start when I log in to Xubuntu. To be precise, I added the following commands:

- **dbus-launch dropbox start** (I had the notorious Dropbox Icon problem and this works it out)
- **/opt/thefanclub/grive-tools/grive-indicator** (to start the Grive Indicator automatically - it doesn't do it by itself)

Unfortunately, i found out that whatever command I add to the start-up is correctly inserted to the list, but it has no effect to Xubuntu.
No program I add starts. The lines are correctly there and "activated", but they have no effect.

If I type the same lines in a terminal (even without "sudo") they work perfectly, but they don't do anything if I put them in start-up.

I'd ike to avoid typing the commands in a terminal everytime I start my machine.

Has anyone had the same problem?
Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Thank you in advance for your kind help!